# Why is my curl cron job not running?

Tags: php, curl, cron

I am trying to figure out why my curl cron job is not executing correctly.  When I run it in the browser it runs just fine however if I run it in command line I get the following output.  I have replaced the actual URL however the url is something like `example.com/file.php?pass=password&t=d`

> root@low [/home/user]# sudo -u user curl URL
>  
>   [1] 13959 root@low
>   [/home/user]# Starting backups for **0** accounts!

The output in the browser runs for all 9, 10, or however many backups I have. Am I just missing a flag in my curl request?

Comment: Do you mean that the URL does not start with `http://`?

Answer (score 4):

You are using the & sign in the command line, so the parameter t gets lost and your script does not get all its input data (and it's probably the same with your cron job, since it's executed shell-wise).

try:

curl 'url'

Checkout http://linuxcommand.org/lts0080.php, search for "Putting a program in the background" for more info on & in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `curl` is typically located in `/usr/bin/curl`. Perhaps you need to run it as absolute path in your cronjob (in case `/usr/bin` is not contained in your default path).
This would typically be the case if it works from commandline but not from cron (as exact same command).